# Getting rid of annoying warnings in Eclipse

Tags: java, eclipse

The following code, where `Config.PREFERENCES_ENABLE` is a `static final boolean`, produces a compiler warning (on all the code after the `if` block and the warning is "Dead Code"), and trying to use `@SuppressWarnings("all")` on it produces a syntax error.  I know I'm being a bit OCD here, but you know how it is.

```
void displayPreferences() {

    if(!Config.PREFERENCES_ENABLED) return;

    startActivityForResult(
            new Intent(this, PrefsActivity.class),
            PREFERENCE_ACTIVITY);
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Aside from changing the Eclipse compiler preferences, there are a few other options you can choose:

1. Specify `@SuppressWarnings("unused")` for the method to suppress the specific warning.
2. Remove the `final` from `Config.PREFERENCES_ENABLED` to satisfy the compiler.
3. Store the preference in some external file and read that at runtime.

The first option at least allows you to keep the unused compiler warning enabled, which might be useful in other parts of code later. The second option might not be desirable if you're really concerned that something might change it during runtime (or perhaps that's even desirable). The third option has the benefit of not hard coding the preference and allowing it be configured in an external file that's easier to change without recompiling code.

Comment: I guess the whole idea of `final` is to allow for dead code stripping at compile-time.

Comment: @EboMike, Right. So without knowing the OP's goal, it is difficult to give a good single answer. These are the options though :)

Answer (score 1):

`Window > Preferences > Java > Compiler > Errors/Warnings > Unused Code`

I think. I don't have Eclipse open in front of me. You can use the filter box in the preferences dialog to find it, too.

Answer (score 0):

Why don't you just write it like this?

```
void displayPreferences() {
    if (Config.PREFERENCES_ENABLED) {
        startActivityForResult(
            new Intent(this, PrefsActivity.class),
            PREFERENCE_ACTIVITY);
    }
}
```